# what does linear_model signifies in sklearn?

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, libraries, linear-regression

In the implementation of **Linear Regression** using Python and other libraries (sklearn) the usual declarations we deploy are

```
from sklearn import linear_model
.......
..
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
...
..
```

I know that `LinearRegresssion` is a **class** in the **library** `sklearn`, then what exactly `linear_model` signifies? and *how class and libraries are usually linked/related?* can you please give a light in this or share relevant pages for my understanding of core concept.

Comment: It's simply a directory in the sklearn library that Python iterprets as a package. If you look in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearnl), you'll see a folder called `linear_model` and in that folder is a `base.py` that defines the `LinearRegression` class. Of course, in order for Python to know that the directory is a package, it has to have the `__init__.py` file, which the folder also contains... [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: I now got the clear picture. That GitHub Repo link that you shared is broke. It has an additional 'L' at the end. The correct link is here - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn from Kewl answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn is a package. It contains the subpackage linear_model, which contains some modules and the class LinearRegression.

You can read more about this structure here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555203/5952674

And explore the structure of sklearn here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn