# I'm getting bug when using "import module [...] module.x" but not when using "from module import x". What's the difference?

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

I have two codes I thought would do the same thing but one of them gives me an error and I'm trying to figure out why. In this example, I'm using the PIL module but would assume it could happen with other modules too:

This works fine:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("./x.png")
```

The following code gives me the error `AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'`:

```
import PIL
image = PIL.Image.open("./x.png")
```

Why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: @JohnGordon - haven't figured out the _why_ yet, but I tested and got the same thing. `Image` is a submodule that is not imported by default. I think that's the deal.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write something like that.  Submodules are not automatically imported.  The first example explicitly imports `Image`, but the second does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, [The import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

> The from form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute

`Image` is a submodule of `PIL`. In your first form, `from PIL import Image` that second step is taken. Python finds the `Image` submodule and imports. In your second form `import PIL`, there was no import of `Image` so it is undefined.

A third option would be

```
import PIL.Image
image = PIL.Image.open("./x.png")
```

Comment: Thanks! This post helped me understand submodules and subpackages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555203/10148922